# data-ng-click event binding to the DOM

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angularjs, I have code in which on clicking the 'button' one new row gets inserted with one 'new button', now in turn that 'new button' also should have ng-click event. The problem is when I try doing this, the the dynamic row with new button gets added but the new button is not getting the click event attached to it. After some research I found that I should compile the element string before adding to the DOM with the help of **"$compile"** service of the angularjs. but then the browser throwing error saying that **'$compiler is not a function'**... Please help. Thank you..!!
following are the code snippets
jsp page code

```
    <td>
        <button type="button" id="clickButton" data-ng-click="insert()"
              class="btn btn-sm btn-default">
                <i class="fa fa-plus fa-lg"></i>
       </button>
   </td>
```

angularjs controller code

```
$scope.insert = function($compile){
          var tableRow ="<tr data-ng-repeat='c in ctrl.client.clientOwnerVOList' id='insertionRow"+count+"'>"+ 
                "<td>"+i+"</td>"+
                "<td class='col-lg-3'><input type='Text' class='form-control' data-ng-model='c.clientOwnerName' name='clientOwnerName{{$index + 1}}' id='Name'></td>"+
                "<td class='col-lg-4'><input type='Email' class='form-control' data-ng-model='c.clientOwnerEmail' name='clientOwnerEmail{{$index + 1}}' id='Email'></td>"+
                "<td class='col-lg-3'><input type='Text' class='form-control' data-ng-model='c.clientOwnerPhone' name='clientOwnerPhone{{$index + 1}}' id='PhoneNo'></td>"+
                "<td><button type='button' data-ng-click=insert() class='btn btn-sm btn-default'><i class='fa fa-plus fa-lg'></i></button></td>"+
                "<td><button type='button' class='btn btn-sm btn-default'  onClick=$(this).closest('tr').remove();><i class='fa fa-trash fa-lg '></i></button></td>"+
                "</tr>";
              var newTableRow = $compile(tableRow)($scope);
              $("#insertionRow").append(newTableRow);
              i++;
          };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a directive that uses compile:

```
 app.directive('dynamic', [ '$compile',
 function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        link: function (scope, ele, attrs) {
            scope.$watch(attrs.dynamic, function (html) {
                ele.html(html);
                $compile(ele.contents())(scope);
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

Then in your html:

```
<div dynamic="tableRow"></div>
```

... wherever you want the table row to show.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you passing $compile as the function argument?You should inject $compile service just as you inject $scope , i.e in your controller/directive.

That might be the reason , it is throwing $compile is not a function error.